# How does one effectively allow multiple users to access an ASP.NET application on a single machine?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, session

We have two types of user - those that move around the building and access the app with PDAs on a wireless network, and those that are deskbound.

Occasionally, a mobile user will try to use one of the deskbound users PCs to access the app. This can often result in data and pages bleeding between the two users. Modifying user behaviour is not an option for very special reasons. The machines in use only run ie 6 or 7.

What are the central issues here, and what are the recommended approaches?

Discursive answers apreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "modifying user behavior?"  Are you saying that a forms based auth scenario is not possible?

Comment: What do you mean by data and page bleeding?

Comment: Sorry - I mean we can't change the way they behave - so asking users to make sure everyone else is logged out of the app on a particular machine before they login won't work - we need to engineer the sw not the users.

Comment: @discursive - data and page bleeding means that either data isn't properly assigned to the correct user onthe db, or users are seeing pages intended fro others in their browser window.

Answer (score 1):

In general, your issue sounds more like a user experience + user training issue than a technology related issue.

In the case where a user enters or updates data while logged in as another user, I think the best way to combat that is to make it very clear **who** is signed into the application from every screen.  For instance, put the user's name in fairly large font near the top of the page, and provide a logout link right next to it.  This is assuming a username/password type of authentication is possible in your system.

You don't necessarily have to ask them to do **lots** of extra work, just another click or two.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Zachary - thanks for the answer. The thing is though, my users absolutely will not engage in a few extra clicks, so I have to be able to do it in a software way.